# Just started learning AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have just started learning AngularJS and I have one simple question. I can't seem to differentiate between when I need to use `{{ something here }}` and when not to use `{{ }}` Is there a trick to knowing when the braces are needed and when they aren't?

Answer (score 3):

`{{}}` are expression evaluators these are to be use in views where there is not an normal js environment so expression can be run normally without it

Expressions are usually placed inside the double curly braces

in html if you normally write `<h1>1+2</h1>` it wont be evaluated but and will be shown as it is. but using `<h1>{{1+2}}</h1>` will result in 3

you can access variables functions also of current scope in this expression evaluators like `{{callme()}}`

Answer (score 0):

{{}}these are expression evaluators. So expression can be used in double curly brackets

```
<p>My first expression: {{ 5 + 5 }}</p>
```

output is:

> ```
>  My first expression: 10
> ```